# Prove that a union of bases for $S$ and $T$ is basis for $S + T$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $S$ and $T$ be subspaces of a vector space $V$. Assume that $B = \{ b_i | i \in I \}$ is a basis for $S \cap T$.
Now, extend $B$ to a basis $A \cup B$ for $S$ where $A = \{ a_j | j \in J \}$ and $A \cap B = \varnothing$.
Also, extend $B$ to a basis $B \cup C$ for $T$ where $C = \{ c_k | k \in K \}$ and $B \cap C = \varnothing$.

Prove that $A \cup B \cup C$ is a basis for $S + T = \{s + t| s \in S, t \in T \}$

I think that we can safely say that $\langle A \cup B \cup C \rangle = S + T$, but how do we prove that $A \cup B \cup C$ is linear independent?

Comment: Suppose some linear combination of the elements is zero. Write that combination as a sum of three vectors ... and show that each is individually zero.  (Each will lie in some space, and be the negative sum of two others...which lie in a space whose intersection with the given sapce consists of just the zero vector.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: suppose
$$
\sum_{i\in I}\beta_i b_i+
\sum_{j\in J}\alpha_j a_j+
\sum_{k\in K}\gamma_k c_k=0
$$
(with all but a finite number of nonzero coefficients). Then
$$
v=\sum_{i\in I}\beta_i b_i+
\sum_{j\in J}\alpha_j a_j=-\sum_{k\in K}\gamma_k c_k\in S\cap T
$$
so you can write
$$
v=\sum_{i\in I}\delta_i b_i
$$
Hence
$$
\sum_{i\in I}\delta_i b_i+\sum_{k\in K}\gamma_k c_k=0
$$
Can you go on?

Comment: Can you explain why $\sum_{i\in I}\beta_i b_i+
\sum_{j\in J}\alpha_j a_j=-\sum_{k\in K}\gamma_k c_k\in S\cap T$. I don't get why it is in $S \cap T$. A basis for $S \cap T$ is $B$.

Comment: @Jxt921 The vectors $b_i$ and $a_j$ belong to $S$; the vectors $c_k$ belong to $T$. So the vector belongs to $S$ and also to $T$.

Comment: I see. So we have $B \cup C$ being linearly independent(as a basis), hence, all $\delta_i$'s and $\gamma_k$'s are zero, hence $\sum_{i\in I}\beta_i b_i+ \sum_{j\in J}\alpha_j a_j = 0$, and, since $A \cup B$ is also linear independent, we have all $b_i$'s and all $a_j$'s being zero. Am i right?

Comment: @Jxt921 Yes, you are!

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $$\sum_I p_i b_i+\sum_J q_j a_j+\sum_K r_kc_k=\mathbf{0}$$ for some scalars $p_i,q_j$ and $r_k$, where at most finitely many are non-zero. Then, since $-\sum_I p_ib_i \in S\cap T$, we have $$\sum_J q_ja_j+\sum_K r_kc_k\in S\cap T.$$ If $q_j \not= 0$ for some $j$ or $r_k\not=0$ for some $k$, then the sum will be in $(S\cup T)\setminus (S\cap T)$. Thus $q_j=0=r_k$ for each $j\in J$ and each $k \in K$.

Then, it follows that $\sum_I p_ib_i$ must be zero and since $b_i$ are linearly independent, $p_i=o$ for each $i \in I$.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. First of all, why $-\sum_I q_ib_i \in A\cap B$ ? We have $A \cap B = \varnothing$.

Comment: Edited, it was supposed to be $S\cap T$ as $B$ is a basis for $S\cap T$.

Comment: @Jxt921 I have edit the question a little bit as well, to make it clearer. Tell me if there is still anything you don't understand.